# Do I need to delete the file index.html generated by the hosting provider from files in Modx?

Tags: modx-revolution

I installed Modx through the built-in hosting download and there are generated files in the files index.html , mchost.php , index.php , config.core.php .
What to do with index.html ? I thought to rename it, but it turned out to be impossible inside the "files" tab -the field with the name is not clickable.
And what are the rest of the above files intended for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`index.php` from MODX is critical and necessary, it's the entry point. `config.core.php` contains path to the MODX core, also necessary file out of the box. The rest do not apply to MODX, you can delete them.